# Sobolev spaces, Finite Element Error Analysis

Tags: sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde, finite-element-method

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a bounded, convex, polygonal domain and $H=\{(u_{1},u_{2})\in H^{\epsilon-\frac{1}{2}}(\Omega)\times H^{\epsilon-\frac{1}{2}}(\Omega),0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}:(div(u_{1},u_{2})\in L^{2}(\Omega)\}$. Now we define a norm $||.||_{H}$ on $H$ by, \
\begin{equation}
||((u_{1},u_{2})||_{H}=||div(u_{1},u_{2})||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}+||u_{1}||_{H^{\epsilon-\frac{1}{2}}(\Omega)}+||u_{2}||_{H^{\epsilon-\frac{1}{2}}(\Omega)}.
\end{equation}
Can we say that $C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})\times C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$ is dense in $H$ with respect to the norm $||.||_{H}$  ?

Comment: If it can be shown that $H(div,\Omega)$ is dense in $H$, then also it is okay.